# MATLAB vectorization: creating a cell array of neighbor index arrays

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization, cell-array

I have a logical matrix `X` of `n` points, where `X(i, j) == 1` if points `i` and `j` are neighbors and `0` otherwise.

I would like to create a cell array `Y` with each entry `Y{i}` (`i` from `1` to `n`) containing an array with the indeces of point `i`'s neighbors.

In other words, I would like to vectorize the following:

```
n = 10;
X = (rand(n, n) < 0.5);

Y = cell(1, 10);
for i = 1:10
    [Y{i}] = find(X(i, :));
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one approach you can use [`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
[R,C] = find(X.') %//'
Y = accumarray(C(:),R(:),[],@(x) {x})
```

If you need each cell to be a row vector, you need to add one transpose there with `x`, like so -

```
Y = accumarray(C(:),R(:),[],@(x) {x.'})
```

As another approach, you can also use [`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), but I don't think this would be a *vectorized* solution -

```
Y  = arrayfun(@(n) R(C==n),1:max(C),'Uni',0)
```

---

If you don't care about the order of elements in each cell, you can avoid the transpose of `X` to get `R` and `C` like so -

```
[R,C] = find(X)
```

Then, interchange the positions of `R` and `C` with the `accumarray` and `arrayfun` based approaches as listed earlier.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, that does the trick. But it looks like voodoo to me! :-) Could you please explain how you're using `accumarray`? I especially don't get the `@x {x}` part.

Comment: @MGA From what I know, that {x} part *accumulates* the data from R based on the subscripts in C and stores as cells of a cell array for each subscript. So, basically those curly braces are signalling to store output as cells.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some more voodoo:

```
Y = mat2cell(nonzeros(bsxfun(@times, X, 1:size(X,1)).').', 1, sum(X,2));
```

The most important function here is [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). To see how the code works, I suggest you observe partial results from innermost outwards: first `bsxfun(@times, X, 1:size(X,1)).'`, then `nonzeros(...)`, etc.